# issue with server middleware when deploying nuxt-app on heroku

Tags: vue.js, express, heroku, deployment, nuxt.js

I'm running into an issue to deploy a nuxt-app with some serverMiddleware code on Heroku.

this is my middleware code which just launch an express app:

```
api/index.js
```

```js
var express = require("express");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world");
});

app.post("/contact", async (req, res) => {
  // let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.exemple.net",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
    }
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: req.body.email,
    to: "contact@email.com",
    subject: "new contact",
    text: req.body.message
  });

  res.end();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

module.exports = {
  path: "/api",
  handler: app
};
```

then i registered this file into `nuxt.config.js`:

```
serverMiddleware: ["~/api/index"],
```

the api works perfectly in dev mode (locally).

I first deployed on heroku with the nuxt target setting set to `static`,
the static content was working perfectly but none of the serverMiddleware code was working (that make senses ^^).

then i switched to `target: 'server'` but now when i deploy i get this message from heroku:

```
✖ Nuxt Fatal Error
Error: Address `0.0.0.0:41828` is already in use
```

i'm sure that i'm missing something but can't find the solution.

just to complete my post i added this line into the package.json file:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "nuxt build"
```

and also a Procfile at the root of my app which contain:

```
web: nuxt start
```

and finally these are my heroku:config settings:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
heroku config:set HOST=0.0.0.0
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

Any advice on the correct way to deploy much appreciated.

Comment: Really complete and clear question with a lot of effort, congratz! (I don't see it often) Does it work locally? Probably some kind of Heroku build issue here. Not sure why it would error tho. Do you have more logs somewhere? Can you try to give it another port? Because the maximum for an HTTP port is `65535` (with some reserved ones): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking) Also, can you maybe wipe the cache and let the dyno hard restart or something? Looks like there is some kind of previous stuck build?